# Transfer PHP variable to next page from a while loop

Tags: php, html

I have it so that my while loop makes a bunch of  tags that link to a page called car.php. On car.php I want it so that the vehicle_id is transferred from the clicked tag within the original page to car.php so I can use that primary key to display all of the other information on the car.php.

Currently, this is my extremely messy while loop, what it currently does is give me the final result only, meaning when I go to car.php it simply gives me the final car owned by a user and none of the other ones. If I remove $i++ it gives the very first car. This happens with every button also, no matter which  tag I click I get the same result, either the first or final result. I basically just want a way to know which  tag was clicked.

```
<?php
                $clicked = 0;
                $i = 0;
                if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                        $cars[] = array(
                            'vehicle_id' => $row['vehicle_id']
                        );
                        ?>
                        
                        <a $i++; href="car"<?php $_SESSION["vehicle_id"]=$cars[$i]['vehicle_id'];?>; class="carrow col-10";?><?php echo $row['vehicle_make']; echo $row['vehicle_model']; echo $row['vehicle_id'];?><hr></a>
                        

                        <?php
                        $i++;
                    }
                    
                    
                    
                    echo var_dump($cars);
                    }   
                    ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should do the following:

declare $cars array outside the loop:

$cars = [];

And within the loop, add vehicle id to $cars array;

Updated solution:

```
<?php
            $clicked = 0;
            $i = 0;
            if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                $cars = [];
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $temp = [];
                    $temp['vehicle_id'] = $row['vehicle_id'];
                    $cars[] = $temp;
                    ?>
                    
                    <a $i++; href="car"<?php $_SESSION["vehicle_id"]=$cars[$i]['vehicle_id'];?>; class="carrow col-10";?><?php echo $row['vehicle_make']; echo $row['vehicle_model']; echo $row['vehicle_id'];?><hr></a>
                    

                    <?php
                    $i++;
                }
                
                
                
                echo var_dump($cars);
                }   
                ?>
```

Hope this helps.

```
<?php
            $clicked = 0;
            $i = 0;
            if ($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {

                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $cars[] = array(
                        'vehicle_id' => $row['vehicle_id']
                    );
                    ?>
                    
                    <a $i++; href="car"<?php $_SESSION["vehicle_id"]=$cars[$i]['vehicle_id'];?>; class="carrow col-10";?><?php echo $row['vehicle_make']; echo $row['vehicle_model']; echo $row['vehicle_id'];?><hr></a>
                    

                    <?php
                    $i++;
                }
                
                
                
                echo var_dump($cars);
                }   
                ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could mean this (broken across several lines for readability)

```
<a 
    href="car.php?vehicle_id=<?php echo $row['vehicle_id']; ?>"
    class="carrow col-10"
>
    <?php echo "{$row['vehicle_make']} {$row['vehicle_model']} {$row['vehicle_id']}"; ?>
    <hr>
</a>
```

On the next page (car.php) you can retrieve it by using $_GET['vehicle_id']

Example

```
if (isset($_GET['vehicle_id'])) {
    $vehicle_id = $_GET['vehicle_id'];
}
```

Comment: This is what i initially tried, but it seems trying to echo onto the next page doesnt work, if i slot the <a> tag you sent me in where the original was it doesn't actually echo it. I don't know if this is just an issue with how i've formatted things but i've basically put what you posted where my a tag was and it doesnt echo

Comment: @Bellimeister Ah you didn't know how to retrieve the variable. I see you've marked the answer correct that's basically a copy of mine.

Comment: @Popnoodles copy of yours? Haha. **Prove me the single line that I copied from this *incomplete answer***. And here is proof that you copied mine without missing a single word. [Check the revision](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75873216/revisions)

Comment: @Bellmeister could you please mark the original answer (this one) as correct. Plagiarism shouldn't be rewarded.

Comment: @AbdullaNilam Mine was posted long before yours. You copied it and changed a couple of things instead of doing the right thing. When someone has answered already, and you need to just add one more line, you just add one more line. Here's a link for you https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: And why should I copy the addendum from your duplicate answer that you should have added to my answer?

Comment: @Popnoodles I don't know why you making this stu** argument. And you've posted tour link as well. What's in there? Again my question is why should I edit Incomplete answer when you didn't get the question properly. Answer should contain Error fix + next Step of if. Don't tell that you didn't copy, ***On the next page (car.php).....***. Haha

Comment: @AbdullaNilam There's no argument. I didn't say that I didn't copy the addendum that you should have just added to my question, instead of copying my answer. https://stackoverflow.com/tour take a read.